1970s comedy movie with tons of car crashes?
This is probably an obscure film because I've checked Wiki lists for all American films released in the mid-70s and can't find it.
It was a comedy and involved tons of cars running into each other in sort of a dirt lot. It was not a "destruction derby" at all. Just a bunch of people mad at each other, crashing into each other, and it seemed like this went on for half the movie! It featured a ton of car destruction and funny characters. 
Had a title like, "The Something Something Something Gang" or similar with about 3 words, but maybe not with "gang" but a similar word. Used to air on TNT or Disney Channel in the late 1980s and early 1990s. Seemed like a Disney movie but I've checked and I do not see it listed.

Do any of the old Herbie movies have a demolition derby scene?

Regular cars or were there cop cars and lorries as well?

Maybe the The Cannonball Run ?

I was gonna ask about Used Cars, but I don't think that would ever be mistaken for a Disney movie

Regular American cars. Not Cannonball run. God... it was so distinctive, but I can't remember the title... It was a comedy and had people crashing into each other because they were mad at each other.

The title was very distinctive, seemed like it was three or four words. "The Something Something Gang" or something like that. "Gang" may not have been in the title but another word like that.

Is it possible you're thinking of "The Love Bug" or "Herbie Rides Again"?  The title you're trying to remember may be "The Apple Dumpling Gang", but that film isn't about cars.

@BillDavis are you crossing wires with "The Apple Dumpling Gang"?

It's not the Apple Dumpling Gang, but had a similar-sounding title.

Possibly The Junkman (1982)?
From "Top 3 Most Destructive, Car-Destroying Films In Movie History"

When all was said and done, this production crashed over 150 cars on film, setting the Guinness World Record in the process.





That's not it, but The Junkman looks like a great movie. Good find. The one I'm talking about could be late 70s. It featured most of the crashes and wrecks in what looked like a dirt lot. Felt like a Disney movie, but may not be.

presumably not the original "Gone in 60 Seconds" either?

Not Gone in 60 Seconds.

How about Steel Arena (1973)?

Dusty Russell shows off his talent as the greatest daredevil on the circuit. Later, he awaits the biggest challenge of his career.

Here is the trailer:




Sorry, not it. It's a comedy and almost felt like a Disney movie.

The comedy movie I saw with the most car involved is "the Blues Brothers".
But they aren't as much crashing as they are pursuing the 2 brothers and some of them crash in the process...
A good movie (overall. The cars themselves are just a side thing, but their involvement, especially near the end, made a lasting impression that made me want to cite this movie in case you just remembered that part)
